# I'm just learning code.I want to know javascript or php code to show hidden paragraph <p>

Tags: javascript, html, text, show, hidden

`<p hidden> Wrong email or password`

html

```
$email=$_POST["login"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

$zz= "Select * from employer  where EMMail='$email' and EMpassword='$password'";
$sql="select * from student where StudentEmail='$email' and StudentPassword='$password'";

if $email && $password !=$zz || $email && $password !=$sql{

}
```

how to show that para when username or password is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

### Using PHP

You can simply just do something like this

```
$failed=true;
if $email && $password !=$zz || $email && $password !=$sql{
  $failed=false;
}
```

and later where this certain paragraph is found:

```
echo "<p ". ($failed?"hidden":"")+">Wrong password!</p>
```

## Different Pages

I would recommend to use different pages like this:

```
login
|--index.php        //loginform
|--login.php
|--fail
|  |--index.php     //with link to login form
home
|--index.php
includes
|--sql.php
```

login/index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Login
    </title>
  <body>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <table>
        <tr><td>User</td><td><input name="user" placeholder="johndoe123/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Pass</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="iluvyou%&-"/></td></tr>
        <tr colspan=2><td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

login/login.php
**Note:** Use prepared statements!!! The method you used is extremly vulnerable to SQL injection and XSS. Also: PLEASE hash the password(s)!

```
<?php
  include "/includes/sql.php";
  $user=$_POST["user"];
  $passtry=$_POST["pass"];
  $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='?'";
  $cmd = $con->prepare($sql);
  $cmd->execute(array($user));
  if($entry=$cmd->fetchObject()){
    $pass=$entry->pass;
  }else{
    header("Location: fail");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(password_verify($passtry,$pass)){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["login"]=true;
    $_SESSION["user"]=$user;
    header("Location: ../home");
  }else{
    header("Location: fail");
    exit(0);
  }
?>
```

fail/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Wrong password!
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Wrong password. <a href="..">Try again!</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

home/index.html

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!$_SESSION["login"]){
    header("Location: ../login/fail");
    exit();
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      <?php echo $_SESSION["user"] ?> - Home
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
     PRIVATE CONTENT!!!
  </body>
</html>
```

*includes/sql.php* depends on your sql engine.

**Note:** In your register form you must save the password using `password_hash()`